# Create JPQL Statement With (:date INTERVAL :field HOUR)

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa

I have this jpql:

```
SELECT m FROM Mark m WHERE DATE_ADD(m.date, INTERVAL m.gmt HOUR) >= :dateParam
```

When I tried to execute this, some errors ocurred. I checked in the Stackoverflow that the INTERVAL statement is not avaiable to JPA queryes, so, I tried to use parameters and I got fail again. How can I do this action using a field in the INTERVAL expression like 'm.gmt'?

Comment: In which JPA documentation do you see JPQL keywords/functions DATE_ADD, INTERVAL and HOUR ? They don't exist. JPQL != SQL. If you really want to use some SQL function directly you look at JPQL "FUNCTION" keyword

Comment: I've tried to use: FUNCTION('DATE_ADD', m.date, INTERVAL m.gmt HOUR) but the same error has ocurred: The expression is not a valid conditional expression.

Comment: but then "INTERVAL m.gmt HOUR" is invalid JPQL too, so what do you expect? Many JPA providers provide an HOUR method, but then you'd have to look in the docs of your chosen JPA provider for what they support

Comment: I'm not understanding man. I thought if I use the FUNCTION keyword to call some native mysql function I would have give the params and the function would be called. If I use FUNCTION('INTERVAL') and FUNCTION('HOUR') inside the FUNCTION('DATE_ADD') it will be fixed?

Comment: the function would be called BUT your argument is not valid! Passing in random text .... man

Comment: Ok man, thanks for help.